# ifelse statement error in r

Tags: r, if-statement

I'm creating a new column (called Environment) in my dataset (called data2) based on another column called "Site" where "1", "2", and "4" correspond to stream sites, "3" and "5" correspond to swamp sites, and "8" corresponds to the river site. Here's my code:

```
data2$Environment<-as.factor(data2$Environment<-ifelse(data2$Site==c("1", "2", "4"), "Stream", ifelse(data2$Site==c("8"),"River" ,"Swamp")))
```

When going through the new Environment column, it attributes the wrong name to the wrong site. For example, instead of 8 corresponding to River, sometimes it corresponds to Stream. This happens for other factors as well for the different combinations.
Why is this happening? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please share a minimum reproducible example. We don't have `data2` so we can't reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0):

How can you check data2$Site taking on one of the c("1", "2", "4") values?

Definitely not by `data2$Site == c("1", "2", "4")`, you should use %in%:

```
data2$Site %in% c("1", "2", "4")
```

Let's work on a reproducible example:

```
data(iris)
```

This well known data set has a column named Species, which takes 3 values: virginica, setosa, and versicolor. This is the full column:

```
> iris$Species
  [1] setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa    
 [10] setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa    
 [19] setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa    
 [28] setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa    
 [37] setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa    
 [46] setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor
 [55] versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor
 [64] versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor
 [73] versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor
 [82] versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor
 [91] versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor
[100] versicolor virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica 
[109] virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica 
[118] virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica 
[127] virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica 
[136] virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica 
[145] virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica
```

When I check if my Species is either setosa or virginica, the first 50 should return YES, the second 50 NO, and the last 50 again YES. Let's see what happens when we check the wrong way:

```
> iris$Species == c('virginica','setosa')
  [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
 [18]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
 [35] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
 [52] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [69] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [86] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[103]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
[120] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[137]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

The first and last 50 records are returned as TRUE-FALSE alternating. Let's do the right way:

```
> iris$Species %in% c('virginica','setosa')
  [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
 [18]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
 [35]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
 [52] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [69] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [86] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
[103]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[120]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[137]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

So that is item number one. Item number two is, you are doing something like:

```
data2$Environment<-as.factor(data2$Environment<-ifelse(blabla))
```

This might even be dangerous, but no comment on that, I've never done a nested assignment like this. My comment is: Why not just `data2$Environment<-as.factor(ifelse(blabla))`? Other than that, your nested ifelse to take care of 3 conditions is correct. Just for comparison, in my example, the equivalent would be:

```
> ifelse(iris$Species %in% c('virginica'),'vi', ifelse(iris$Species %in% c('setosa'),'se', 've'))
  [1] "se" "se" "se" "se" "se" "se" "se" "se" "se" "se" "se" "se" "se" "se" "se" "se" "se" "se" "se" "se"
 [21] "se" "se" "se" "se" "se" "se" "se" "se" "se" "se" "se" "se" "se" "se" "se" "se" "se" "se" "se" "se"
 [41] "se" "se" "se" "se" "se" "se" "se" "se" "se" "se" "ve" "ve" "ve" "ve" "ve" "ve" "ve" "ve" "ve" "ve"
 [61] "ve" "ve" "ve" "ve" "ve" "ve" "ve" "ve" "ve" "ve" "ve" "ve" "ve" "ve" "ve" "ve" "ve" "ve" "ve" "ve"
 [81] "ve" "ve" "ve" "ve" "ve" "ve" "ve" "ve" "ve" "ve" "ve" "ve" "ve" "ve" "ve" "ve" "ve" "ve" "ve" "ve"
[101] "vi" "vi" "vi" "vi" "vi" "vi" "vi" "vi" "vi" "vi" "vi" "vi" "vi" "vi" "vi" "vi" "vi" "vi" "vi" "vi"
[121] "vi" "vi" "vi" "vi" "vi" "vi" "vi" "vi" "vi" "vi" "vi" "vi" "vi" "vi" "vi" "vi" "vi" "vi" "vi" "vi"
[141] "vi" "vi" "vi" "vi" "vi" "vi" "vi" "vi" "vi" "vi"
```

Hence if you just change your double equals to %in%'s you should be good.